# Assigning objects within public method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wish to create a public method on my masterpage, that I can call from within every subpage. 
I am trying to wrap my head around how this should be done.

On my subpages I've made this method to fill a panel with an errormessage.

```
protected void errorMessage (string errorText) {
  HtmlGenericControl divTag = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
  Panel_Name.Controls.Add(divTag);
  divTag.InnerHtml = errorText;
}
```

Now if I were to make this function public on my masterpage, It wont recognize my Panel as it havent been showed yet. I'm guessing the answer involves `FindControl`
(Sorry for my rubbish code english)

How should I do this ?

Comment: So you want to show an error message in some of your master's content-pages from the masterpage itself? Why don't you use a `Label` on the `MasterPage` instead? What if somebody adds a page that uses this master but forgets to add your magic error-panel?

Comment: I wish to output this errormessage in different locations of my content pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be fair, for your scenario, I would use a UserControl (.ascx) on your Pages (.aspx).

Then, in the UserControl, have your error message markup, such as:

**Code front (ErrorMessage.ascx)**

```
  <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PanelErrorMessage" /> // creates a <div>
```

**Code behind (ErrorMessage.ascx.cs)**

```
public string ErrorMessage 
{ 
    get {}
    set 
    {
         PanelErrorMessage.Text = value; // sets the panel text (<div>text</div>) to value when property is set
    }
}
```

Use your UserControl on your Page (you'll need to define this as a control tag on your page too with the prefix/suffix):

```
<myControls:ErrorMessage runat="server" ID="MyErrorControl" />
```

You can also do this in many places on your page, if you require different errors.

Then, when you have an error, you'll simply do:

```
MyErrorControl.ErrorMessage = "This is my error message";
```

Job done!

Comment: Thank you sir! 
This seems like a fitting solution to my problem.